# how to call a java script function in v8 use arg.this?

Tags: v8

I  want call javascript callback in V8,for example :

```js
var test = function(){
 this.name = 'wmd';
};
test.prototype.hello = function(level, message) {
 console.log('[' + level + '] : ' + message);
 console.log('[name] : ' + this.name);
};
```

var proxy = new test();
hello.test(proxy.hello);

```js
code in v8 like this :

const unsigned argc = 2;
Local<Value> argv[argc] = {
  Local<Value>::New(Number::New(1)) ,
  Local<Value>::New(String::New("Test Message"))
};

s_logCallback->Call(args.This(), argc, argv);
```

callback is success ,but can't excute console.log('[name] : ' + this.name);this.name is undefined ,but i want t use like this  what should i do ?  Function.Call(Local),..,..)  how to set the first param ?